# Detect lowest vertical div on page

Tags: html, positioning

I have a problem trying to keep my footer div at the bottom of all my others.
When I call the footer from my main content div I get errors with long side bars overlapping the footer.

But when I try calling the footer from the sidebar div then I have the same problem with the main content div.

Getting one to work seems to break the other.
Is there a way I can get these 's to check if they are the lowest elements on a page and, if so, only then call a function?

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Comment: Could you please provide some HTML/CSS?

Comment: ''Detect lowest vertical div on page" - possible with javascript/jquey, but i am not sure do you need it at all (you didn't tagged it)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly your trying to do...You haven't posted any code and your question lacks detail.

But if your trying to get the **LAST DIV** in your document you could use this `Jquery` function.

```
$('div').last();
```

This will get the last div on the page. You can chain methods to this like `$('div').last().addClass().remove()` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, but I managed to find a really simple solution..
I found that using structured divs to hold the main content, the sidebar & the footer meant that the browser naturally kept them apart.

So I ended up with something like this;

```
<div id="main_holder" >

<div style="width: 900px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 500px;">

// Main Content Code Goes Here

 </div>

 <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">

// Side Bar Code Goes Here

 </div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>

// Footer Code Goes Here

</div>
```

I didn't show you my code cause it's ugly..
http://jsfiddle.net/p3B4s/47/